# Localhost de XAMPP y WAMP no muestran algunas carpetas

Tags: php, xampp, localhost, wamp

ya llevo bastante tiempo tratando de solucionar un problema que tengo.
Tengo unas carpetas en mi servidor local, probé instalando WAMP y XAMPP. Con ambos tengo los mismos resultados:

- app
- public

Cuando voy al navegador y escribo localhost, no me muestra la carpeta app, esto no solamente me pasa con esta carpeta, si no que cuando creo algun archivo, en cualquier lugar del servidor, con el nombre "header" o que comience por "header" tampoco me lo muestra y tampoco me deja acceder a través de `include` o `include_once` o algún otro método de llamado de archivos.

[image: Las carpetas que creo en el servidor local]

[image: Lo que veo cuando accedo desde el navegador al localhost]

Comment: Estas seguro que se esta apuntando a la misma carpeta en el servidor? Generalmente es una carpeta dentro del WAMP/XAMP que instalaste. Si creas otra carpeta con nombre al azar aparece en el "Index of"?

Answer (score 1):

He encontrado la solución simplemente había un .htaccess que tenía la linea `Options All -indexes` la quité y ahora me muestras todos los directorios y archivos. Estuve viendo y también funciona cambiando esa misma línea por: `Options All +indexes`